# Can Greasemonkey cause the displayed title to change

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, title

I want to change the title showing in a page based on information I pick up from within the page (eg to show the number of inbox messages)

`document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML="foo";` does change the title tag, but firefox does not update the displayed title (in window and tags) when this happens.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try using this instead:

```
document.title = "MyTitle";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try setting [document.title](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.title) to the new value